# error occurs: class SubclassInSamePackage is public, should be declared in a file named SubclassInSamePackage.java

Tags: java

Please help me out with the code the error is

```
class SubclassInSamePackage is public, should be declared in a file named SubclassInSamePackage.java
```

Program:

```
package pckage1;

class BaseClass {

    public int x = 10;
private int y = 10;
protected int z = 10;
int a = 10; //Implicit Default Access Modifier
public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
private int getY() {
    return y;
}
private void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
protected int getZ() {
    return z;
}
protected void setZ(int z) {
    this.z = z;
}
int getA() {
    return a;
}
void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}
}


public class SubclassInSamePackage extends BaseClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    BaseClass rr = new BaseClass();
    rr.z = 0;
    SubclassInSamePackage subClassObj = new SubclassInSamePackage();
    //Access Modifiers - Public
    System.out.println("Value of x is : " + subClassObj.x);
    subClassObj.setX(20);
    System.out.println("Value of x is : " + subClassObj.x);
    //Access Modifiers - Public
    //      If we remove the comments it would result in a compilaton
    //      error as the fields and methods being accessed are private
    /*      System.out.println("Value of y is : "+subClassObj.y);

     subClassObj.setY(20);

     System.out.println("Value of y is : "+subClassObj.y);*/
    //Access Modifiers - Protected
    System.out.println("Value of z is : " + subClassObj.z);
    subClassObj.setZ(30);
    System.out.println("Value of z is : " + subClassObj.z);
    //Access Modifiers - Default
    System.out.println("Value of x is : " + subClassObj.a);
    subClassObj.setA(20);
    System.out.println("Value of x is : " + subClassObj.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: your main class is `SubclassInSamePackage` so your file name should be `SubclassInSamePackage.java`.

Answer (score 0):

There can be only one public class in a file and the name of that class should match with that of the filename.

If you want to create multiple classes in the same file, you can mark them as private or "blank" but not public.